# How to convert a text file to byte data and publish to XYZ queue using jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there a way to convert a text file to byte format and publish the message to XYZ queue using jMeter ?

Comment: Why do you want to use JMeter for this?

Comment: @Rafael, We have a requirment for Automation , where I  want to convert the data from the text file to Byte array of 48 Bytes in binary format and then push it to XYZ queues.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7  it can be done as :

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file.getPath());
```

From Java Docs :

> Read all the bytes from a file. The method ensures that the file is
>   closed when all bytes have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime
>   exception, is thrown.
>
> Note that this method is intended for simple cases where it is
>   convenient to read all bytes into a byte array. It is not intended for
>   reading in large files.
>
> Throws: 
> **IOException** - if an I/O error occurs reading from the stream
>   
> **OutOfMemoryError** - if an array of the required size cannot be
>   allocated, for example the file is larger that 2GB 
> **SecurityException** -
>   In the case of the default provider, and a security manager is
>   installed, the checkRead method is invoked to check read access to the
>   file.